# Android AVD Manager: Resolution differs between overview and configuration screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

It's been a few years since I last worked with the Android emulator and AVD manager, I usually worked with real devices. Now it's time that I need to create an AVD again in the Android studio.

I am wondering about this behavior: the resolution of the AVD differs between the AVD overview and the AVD configuration. See the screen below.

I want to create a Nexus 10 AVD, and the correct screen resolution is 2560x1600 with xhdpi. This is also what I see when I enter the AVD configuration. But in the AVD overview, the screen resolution is shown as 800x1280 xhdpi. Why is that?
(And starting the emulator seems to actually use a 800x1280 resolution).

[image]

And /Users/MyUser/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_19_2.avd/hardware-qemu.ini holds:

```
hw.lcd.width = 800
hw.lcd.height = 1280
hw.lcd.depth = 16
hw.lcd.density = 320
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi I have the same problem, I solved unchecking the **Enable Device Frame Check**.

```
Show Advanced Settings->Device Frame->Enable Device Frame Check.
```

Then Click Finish and you will see that the resolution change to the correct.

Comment: Does anyone know how to enable device frame and keep the same resolution?